# Issues using a psql -v variable with jsonb_set

Tags: postgresql, bash, psql, jsonb

Pretty obscure situation and a couple hours of trying different things with no luck.

I have a bash script which restores a production database backup locally. Part of the script runs some SQL to set things in the database.

One of those items is setting the correct `slack_token` in a `slack_details` table. Here's how I run the bash script:

```bash
$ ./restore-prod-database.sh -t "xoxb-1234567-1234....."
```

The script has a line which triggers running a .sql file like this:

```bash
psql -h $DATABASE_HOST -d $DATABASE_NAME -a -v slack_token=$SLACK_TOKEN -f restore-populate-slack-details.sql
```

Finally, the SQL does something like this:

```sql
UPDATE slack_details
SET installation = jsonb_set(installation, '{bot,token}', ('"' || :slack_token ||'"')::jsonb)
WHERE id = 1;
```

No matter what I try, whether its concatenating the :slack_token with quotes, passing it in with quotes, using single quotes and " I get the following error:

> UPDATE slack_details SET installation = jsonb_set(installation,
> '{bot,token}', ('"' || :slack_token ||'"')::jsonb) WHERE id = 1;
> psql:restore-populate-slack-details.sql:61: ERROR:  column "xoxb" does
> not exist LINE 2: ... = jsonb_set(installation, '{bot,token}', ('"' ||
> xoxb-12345...

Quick note, installation is a jsonb column and the following code works fine, moment I use the -v variable it doesn't work:

```sql
UPDATE slack_details
SET installation = jsonb_set(installation, '{bot,token}', ('"' || '123456' ||'"')::jsonb)
WHERE id = 1; --- works fine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To inject the `:slack_token` variable as a literal in the SQL query, the proper syntax to use is `:'slack_token'`.

From the [psql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION) in "SQL interpolation":

> When a value is to be used as an SQL literal or identifier, it is
> safest to arrange for it to be quoted. To quote the value of a
> variable as an SQL literal, write a colon followed by the variable
> name in single quotes. To quote the value as an SQL identifier, write
> a colon followed by the variable name in double quotes. These
> constructs deal correctly with quotes and other special characters
> embedded within the variable value

The query could be written as:

```
UPDATE slack_details
SET installation = jsonb_set(installation, '{bot,token}', ('"' || :'slack_token' ||'"')::jsonb)
WHERE id = 1;
```

Besides, as commented below by @jjanes, the construction of the jsonb value should be simplified and made safer by using `to_jsonb`, otherwise the lack of quoting inside the token might lead to invalid json strings with certain values of `:slack_token`:

```
UPDATE slack_details
SET installation = jsonb_set(
       installation,
       '{bot,token}',
       to_jsonb(:'slack_token'::text)
) WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: Yes.  But to improve it further, I think he would want to use to_jsonb() not concatenating literal double quotes to the thing.   `to_jsonb(:'slack_token'::text)`  That way it will work correctly if the token happens to contain a literal double quote.

Comment: @jjanes: good point, answer updated.

Comment: amazing, thank you!